# iPad application frameworks

Tags: ipad, frameworks

what are the frameworks available for iPad application development?

Answer (score 0):

Last I looked, there are none.  You can use the iPad development kit, but that's it.  The Apple license for developing on the iPad/iPhone (used to) preclude the creation of frameworks.

Comment: Preclude the creation of frameworks? I guess it depends on how you define frameworks... at the highest end, where the language could be anything, yeah, those used to be precluded. At a lower level, though, for example a "newsreader framework" in Objective-C, those always have been and still are fine.

Comment: To my recollection, there was a line in the license agreement that specifically and explicitly said "you cannot create frameworks".  whether that changed or was clarified, I don't know (I decided that the license was too restrictive to agree to it).